Is there a way to split the text output from one cell to multiple cells?
I have written a function where I am trying to comment on the results of correlation data. After generating the correlations,I need to provide a heading under the results titled "Correlation commentary" (in a new row) followed by sub-headings for each pair of the following data

Weight / Body Fat
Weight / BMI
Body Fat / BMI
Age / BMI
Height / BMI
Body Fat / Bone Density
Bone Density / Weight.

The commentary should provide an analysis of the results (e.g.weak or strong correlation) followed by possible health/lifestyle issues (as per the IF statements).
Once this is done, I similarly require to output in a a new row another heading titled "Insurance Risk Management strategies". Then under this heading create sub-headings which provide insurance risk strategies to be employed for each pair of data (again as per the IF statements).
At the moment I am only able to output everything in one cell which makes the results look very clumsy. Below is the code:
Function GenerateCommentary(correlationResults As Variant) As String
    Dim commentaryText As String

    commentaryText = "Please note that this commentary is based on general correlations and should not be considered as medical advice. Always consult with a healthcare professional for personalized guidance." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

    commentaryText = commentaryText & "Correlation commentary:" & vbNewLine
    commentaryText = commentaryText & "Weight and Body Fat: " & Format(correlationResults(1), "0.000") & vbNewLine
    commentaryText = commentaryText & "Weight and BMI: " & Format(correlationResults(2), "0.000") & vbNewLine
    commentaryText = commentaryText & "Body Fat and BMI: " & Format(correlationResults(3), "0.000") & vbNewLine
    commentaryText = commentaryText & "Age and BMI: " & Format(correlationResults(4), "0.000") & vbNewLine
    commentaryText = commentaryText & "Height and BMI: " & Format(correlationResults(5), "0.000") & vbNewLine
    commentaryText = commentaryText & "Body Fat and Bone Density: " & Format(correlationResults(6), "0.000") & vbNewLine
    commentaryText = commentaryText & "Bone Density and Weight: " & Format(correlationResults(7), "0.000") & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

    ' Weight and Body Fat
    commentaryText = commentaryText & "Weight and Body Fat Correlation: " & vbNewLine
    If correlationResults(1) > 0.7 Then
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "There is a strong positive correlation between weight and body fat. This suggests that as weight increases, body fat tends to increase as well. This relationship is common and can be influenced by factors such as diet, exercise, and genetics." & vbNewLine
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "Possible health impacts: Increased risk of obesity-related conditions such as heart disease, diabetes, and certain cancers." & vbNewLine
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "Lifestyle tips: Focus on a balanced diet rich in fruits, vegetables, and lean proteins. Incorporate regular physical activity, aiming for at least 150 minutes of moderate exercise per week." & vbNewLine
    ElseIf correlationResults(1) > 0.3 Then
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "There is a moderate positive correlation between weight and body fat. This suggests some relationship between weight increase and body fat increase, but other factors may also be influencing these measures." & vbNewLine
    Else
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "There is a weak or no significant correlation between weight and body fat in this dataset. This could suggest that other factors, such as muscle mass, may be influencing weight more significantly than body fat." & vbNewLine
    End If
    commentaryText = commentaryText & vbNewLine

    ' Weight and BMI
    commentaryText = commentaryText & "Weight and BMI Correlation: " & vbNewLine
    If correlationResults(2) > 0.9 Then
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "There is a very strong positive correlation between weight and BMI, which is expected as BMI is calculated using weight." & vbNewLine
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "Health consideration: While BMI is a useful screening tool, it doesn't account for factors like muscle mass. Consider other measures like body fat percentage and waist circumference for a more comprehensive health assessment." & vbNewLine
    Else
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "The correlation between weight and BMI is not as strong as typically expected. This could indicate unusual body compositions in the dataset or potential data inconsistencies." & vbNewLine
    End If
    commentaryText = commentaryText & vbNewLine

    ' Body Fat and BMI
    commentaryText = commentaryText & "Body Fat and BMI Correlation: " & vbNewLine
    If correlationResults(3) > 0.7 Then
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "There is a strong positive correlation between body fat and BMI. This suggests that as BMI increases, body fat percentage tends to increase as well." & vbNewLine
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "Lifestyle tip: Focus on body composition rather than just weight. Incorporate strength training into your exercise routine to build lean muscle mass, which can help improve your body composition and metabolic health." & vbNewLine
    ElseIf correlationResults(3) > 0.3 Then
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "There is a moderate positive correlation between body fat and BMI. While there is some relationship, other factors may also be influencing these measures." & vbNewLine
    Else
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "There is a weak or no significant correlation between body fat and BMI in this dataset. This could suggest that the sample includes individuals with diverse body compositions, such as athletes with high muscle mass." & vbNewLine
    End If
    commentaryText = commentaryText & vbNewLine

    ' Age and BMI
    commentaryText = commentaryText & "Age and BMI Correlation: " & vbNewLine
    If correlationResults(4) > 0.3 Then
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "There is a moderate positive correlation between age and BMI. This suggests a tendency for BMI to increase with age, which is common due to factors like decreased metabolism and reduced physical activity." & vbNewLine
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "Lifestyle tip: As you age, pay extra attention to maintaining an active lifestyle and a balanced diet. Regular exercise, including both cardio and strength training, can help maintain a healthy BMI as you get older." & vbNewLine
    Else
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "There is a weak or no significant correlation between age and BMI in this dataset. This could suggest that the sample includes individuals who maintain consistent body compositions across different age groups." & vbNewLine
    End If
    commentaryText = commentaryText & vbNewLine

    ' Body Fat and Bone Density
    commentaryText = commentaryText & "Body Fat and Bone Density Correlation: " & vbNewLine
    If correlationResults(6) < -0.3 Then
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "There is a moderate negative correlation between body fat and bone density. This could suggest that higher body fat is associated with lower bone density, which may increase the risk of osteoporosis." & vbNewLine
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "Health tip: Engage in weight-bearing exercises and ensure adequate calcium and vitamin D intake to support bone health. Consult with a healthcare provider about bone density screening, especially if you're at higher risk for osteoporosis." & vbNewLine
    Else
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "There is no strong negative correlation between body fat and bone density in this dataset. However, maintaining a healthy body composition and engaging in weight-bearing exercises is still important for overall health and bone strength." & vbNewLine
    End If
    commentaryText = commentaryText & vbNewLine

    ' Insurance Risk Management Strategies
    commentaryText = commentaryText & "Insurance Risk Management Strategies:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

    ' Weight and Body Fat
    commentaryText = commentaryText & "Weight and Body Fat:" & vbNewLine
    If correlationResults(1) > 0.7 Then
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "High correlation suggests increased health risks. Consider:" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Offering wellness programs focusing on weight management" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Providing incentives for maintaining a healthy BMI" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Implementing nutrition education programs" & vbNewLine
    ElseIf correlationResults(1) > 0.3 Then
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "Moderate correlation present. Consider:" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Promoting regular health check-ups" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Offering discounts for gym memberships" & vbNewLine
    Else
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "Low correlation. Monitor trends and consider:" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Educating clients on the importance of overall health, not just weight" & vbNewLine
    End If
    commentaryText = commentaryText & vbNewLine

    ' Weight and BMI
    commentaryText = commentaryText & "Weight and BMI:" & vbNewLine
    If correlationResults(2) > 0.9 Then
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "Very high correlation as expected. Risk management strategies:" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Implement tiered pricing based on BMI ranges" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Offer coverage for weight loss surgeries for high-risk individuals" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Provide resources for healthy weight maintenance" & vbNewLine
    Else
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "Unexpected correlation. Consider:" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Investigating potential data anomalies" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Using additional health metrics for risk assessment" & vbNewLine
    End If
    commentaryText = commentaryText & vbNewLine

    ' Body Fat and BMI
    commentaryText = commentaryText & "Body Fat and BMI:" & vbNewLine
    If correlationResults(3) > 0.7 Then
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "Strong correlation indicates increased health risks. Strategies:" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Offer premium discounts for clients who maintain healthy body fat percentages" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Provide coverage for body composition assessments" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Partner with fitness centers to offer discounted memberships" & vbNewLine
    ElseIf correlationResults(3) > 0.3 Then
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "Moderate correlation present. Consider:" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Implementing wellness programs focused on body composition improvement" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Offering nutrition counseling as part of coverage" & vbNewLine
    Else
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "Weak correlation. Strategies:" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Focus on overall health rather than just BMI in risk assessments" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Consider offering more comprehensive health screenings" & vbNewLine
    End If
    commentaryText = commentaryText & vbNewLine

    ' Age and BMI
    commentaryText = commentaryText & "Age and BMI:" & vbNewLine
    If correlationResults(4) > 0.3 Then
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "Moderate positive correlation. Risk management strategies:" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Implement age-specific wellness programs" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Offer coverage for age-related health screenings" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Provide resources for maintaining healthy weight as people age" & vbNewLine
    Else
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "Weak correlation. Consider:" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Focusing on individual health profiles rather than age-based assumptions" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Offering personalized health plans based on multiple factors" & vbNewLine
    End If
    commentaryText = commentaryText & vbNewLine

    ' Body Fat and Bone Density
    commentaryText = commentaryText & "Body Fat and Bone Density:" & vbNewLine
    If correlationResults(6) < -0.3 Then
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "Moderate negative correlation indicates potential risks. Strategies:" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Offer coverage for bone density screenings" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Provide education on osteoporosis prevention" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Consider premium incentives for maintaining healthy body composition and bone density" & vbNewLine
    Else
        commentaryText = commentaryText & "No strong negative correlation. Consider:" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Promoting overall bone health awareness" & vbNewLine & _
            "- Offering coverage for preventive measures like calcium and vitamin D supplements" & vbNewLine
    End If
    commentaryText = commentaryText & vbNewLine

    GenerateCommentary = commentaryText
End Function


Since, you do not process any existing data, may I know why writing that in code and not directly in the cells you need? It would be much simpler. Are you guided by the principle "why simple when complicated is possible*? :) Otherwise, supposing you need placing any cell row on an Excel row and each row to be split in columns by its delimiter (" / ") you should firstly declare an array (arrFin) and intermediary arrays to firstly split by vbNewLine, then each line split by the delimiter and load the final array accordingly. Finally, you only need to drop the array content, at once.

Return the output to a variable and then split the string using vbNewLine as a delimiter to create an array. Once you have the array , simply use resize to output to multiple cells.
Here is an example
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim commentaryText As String
    
    commentaryText = "There is a strong positive correlation between weight and body fat. This suggests that as weight increases, body fat tends to increase as well. This relationship is common and can be influenced by factors such as diet, exercise, and genetics." & vbNewLine
    commentaryText = commentaryText & "Possible health impacts: Increased risk of obesity-related conditions such as heart disease, diabetes, and certain cancers." & vbNewLine
    commentaryText = commentaryText & "Lifestyle tips: Focus on a balanced diet rich in fruits, vegetables, and lean proteins. Incorporate regular physical activity, aiming for at least 150 minutes of moderate exercise per week."
    
    Dim MyAr As Variant
    
    MyAr = Split(commentaryText, vbNewLine)
    
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(MyAr) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(MyAr)
End Sub

Output


If you're using this function as a UDF on a worksheet, split the output into cells with:
=TEXTSPLIT(GenerateCommentary(<datarange>),,CHAR(13))

This will 'spill' the output down a column, using as many cells as needed (provided they're all previously empty, otherwise you'll get the #SPILL! error.)
